# Error Receiving broadcast Intent ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcastreceiver, activity-lifecycle

I am new to android .I am getting a runtime exception says "Error receiving broadcast Intent ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED ".I instantiate my receiver in onCreate() of my activity then I register my receiver in onResume() and unregistered it in onPause() methods. 
Actually i want to set text Charging and Not Charging  according to the charging mode  of my app

```
package com.example.mrfrag.firebattery;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

TextView batteryplus,temp,setting,plug,charging,battery;
private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
IntentFilter ifilter =new IntentFilter();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    batteryplus=  findViewById(R.id.batteryplus);
    temp =  findViewById(R.id.temp);
    setting=  findViewById(R.id.setting);
    plug=  findViewById(R.id.plug);
    charging=  findViewById(R.id.charging);
    battery=  findViewById(R.id.battery);
    mReceiver=new PowerConnectionReceiver();
    ifilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED);
    ifilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED);
    ifilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, ifilter);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}

public class PowerConnectionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public PowerConnectionReceiver(){

    }
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent batteryStatus) {
        int status = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, 
-1);

        boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING 
 ||
                status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;
        if (isCharging) {

            plug.setText("CHARGING");
        } else {

            plug.setText("NOT CHARGING");

        }
        int  health = 
    batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_HEALTH,0);
        batteryplus.setText(ConvoHealth(health));
        String  technology = 
    batteryStatus.getExtras().getString(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TECHNOLOGY);
        setting.setText(technology);
        float  tpr   = ((float) 
 batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE,0)) / 10.0f;
        temp.setText( String.valueOf(tpr) + "°C / " + 
 String.valueOf(tpr*1.8+32)+"F"+"\n");
        int  voltage = 
  batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_VOLTAGE,0);
        charging.setText(voltage+ " mV");
        int  mah = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(String.valueOf
   (BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_CAPACITY),0);
        battery.setText(mah+ " Mah");

    }
}

private String ConvoHealth(int health){
    String result;
    switch(health){
        case BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_COLD:
            result = "COLD";
            break;
        case BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_DEAD:
            result = "DEAD";
            break;
        case BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_GOOD:
            result = "GOOD";
            break;
        case BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_OVERHEAT:
            result = "OVERHEAT";
            break;
        case BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_OVER_VOLTAGE:
            result = "OVER VOLTAGE";
            break;
        case BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_UNKNOWN:
            result = "UNKNOWN";
            break;
        case BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_UNSPECIFIED_FAILURE:
            result = "UNSPECIFIED_FAILURE";
            break;
        default:
            result = "Unknown";
    }
     return result;
 }

}
```

[This is my AndroidManifest.xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1eAZ.png)

[This is Runtime exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYNh8.png)

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting this exception is because of following line:

```
String  technology = 
    batteryStatus.getExtras().getString(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TECHNOLOGY);
        setting.setText(technology);
```

The above line is throwing null pointer. This extra is only available for `Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED`. So either remove it or add condition

```
if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED)){
    String  technology = 
    batteryStatus.getExtras().getString(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TECHNOLOGY);
        setting.setText(technology);
     setting.setText(technology);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Sagar .....Actually even if i commented my whole code inside the onReceive() method then also it gives me an exception and broke my app during disconnecting my charger. I think your point is correct but the problem is something else may be .I tried your code as well but it didn't work for me ...

Comment: If i made my broadcast receiver class in a separate file then it works and never broke my app during discharging.(i used toast messages here).But i want to set the text of the textview located in my HomeActivity layout during the disconnecting time  of my charger .....What should i do ??

Comment: i Got the solution btw ...I simply make my Broadcast receiver inside OnCreate method and then register it their as well...It Works for me

Comment: @FIRE If you un-register in onPause, then the broadcast won't work. You just need to ensure there are not exceptions in your Receiver

Comment: As you said ..what i did i simply remove onPause and onResume ....It Works Fine....i unregistered it in onDestroy